# Page Flickering on Dropdown change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, flicker

I'm using a drop down list to select the customer. The page flicker twice on selecting the customer and I don't know how to rectify it. Can someone please help me solve the problem?

**My Drop Down SelectedIndexChange Code**

```
protected void ReceiverDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ReceiverDropDown.SelectedValue != null && ReceiverDropDown.SelectedValue != "0")
    {            
        string benId = ReceiverDropDown.SelectedValue;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "AddDetails('" + benId + "');", true);
    }
}
```

**Code using Update Panel**

```html
<td>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updTerms" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList Width="180px" CssClass="select_quo_one" ID="ReceiverDropDown" 
                runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ReceiverDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ReceiverDropDown" />
    </Triggers>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: This is due to a Postback to the server - you need to read and understand the control life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid page flickering you can make use of update panel. Bind the DropDownList inside update panel.

**Markup:**

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updTerms">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ReceiverDropDown" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Trigger>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ReceiverDropDown"  />
    </Trigger>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Is your selected index changed working..please check it with a breakpoint?

Comment: Page does not load because you have placed an update panel..it avoids flickering and the particular portion of the page under update panel is loaded..So we can avoid full page postbacks..In this case the when dropdown's selectedindexchanged works the portion of page containing dropdown is loading not the complete page,Regards...

Comment: Is your any part of the code not working or any other problems regarding update panel?

Comment: actually after selecting the customer name it should display the details below..after using updatepanel its not displaying..

Comment: Below means where are you showing the customer details?On which control?

Comment: ok..That box I saw is a panel or div or any other controls?If so pleas include it also inside the update panel..So that it also get updated when selecting the dropdown,Regards..

Answer (score 0):

Use update field like:

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlRefresh" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity"  runat="server" Width="50px"
                     onkeydown="ClearErrorMessages()" onkeypress="return allowNumeric(event)"
                     ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged"  Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>'
                     AutoPostBack = "true"  ondragstart="return false;"
                     ondrop="return false;" />               
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```