# Change of code in browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm using a drop down list for selecting customer, from that i need to remove the setTimeout  which i shown in the image, i don't know from where to remove it..can any one suggest me from where it loads..my browser alone show the `<select .. >`, i need to know from where it loads..

```
<td><asp:DropDownList Width="180px" CssClass="select_quo_one" ID="ReceiverDropDown" 
                            runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ReceiverDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>
```

**My Browser Code:**

[image]

Comment: That is automatically generated by the DropDownList control because AutoPostBack is set to true. Why do you need to remove the setTimeout?

Comment: flickering occurs in my page so i have to remove the setTimeout value..

Comment: The setTimeout doesn't have anything to do with the flickering. The flickering is because the DropDownList is doing a postback every time it is changed bc AutoPostBack is set to true and this causes the page to refresh. If you are not doing anything server side immediately after a customer is selected (like loading other customer info on the page), then you can just set AutoPostBack to false

Comment: if i set Autopostback to false.. my drop down dosent works..

Comment: Then you'll need to post more of your code in order to diagnose the issue. What do you mean "my drop down list doesn't work"? Is there an error, or items aren't loaded or what? Can you post the page load method and the ReceiverDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606299/page-flickering-on-dropdown-change  please look this is my another post on same issue..

Comment: Your selected index change event is doing nothing but registering Javascript to be called, so why are you doing the AutoPostBack? Also you shouldn't post duplicate questions on the same issue bc it clutters the boards.

Comment: sorry.. can you please suggest what is the solution to over come the problem..

Comment: My suggestion is in my answer, however you still have not posted enough of your code to give specific examples

Comment: please have up code look ..

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout is automatically generated by the DropDownList control because AutoPostBack is set to true.

From [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbackoptions.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbackoptions.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The JavaScript setTimeout method is used with the _doPostBack method to ensure that the user action completes before the postback occurs.

**Edit:**
"flickering occurs in my page so i have to remove the setTimeout value.. –  user3595072 17 mins ago"

The setTimeout itself is not (directly) causing the page flickering. The flickering is because the DropDownList is doing a postback every time it is changed bc AutoPostBack is set to true and this causes the page to refresh. If you are not doing anything server side immediately after a customer is selected (like loading other customer info on the page), then you can just set AutoPostBack to false. Otherwise you can look into using an UpdatePanel on your page, or use something like AJAX calls to do your processing without a full postback.

**Edit 2:**

Since you are only adding javascript within your AutoPostBack event, you can add a jQuery reference (if you do not have one already) by adding the following to your ASPX page:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then set AutoPostBack="false" on your DropDownList and add this javascript to accomplish the same thing that your AutoPostBack was doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=ReceiverDropDown.ClientID %>').on('change', function (e) {
            var benId = $(this).val();
            if (benId != '' && benId != '0') {
                AddDetails(benId);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try my suggestion in Edit #2 listed above?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have a few choices -

1) Remove the AutoPostBack - this will stop the SelectedIndexChanged event firing but as you only seem to be popping up an alert you could probably recreate this client side.

2) Put the DropDownList in an UpdatePanel as explained to you in your other question, you may need to do a bit of debugging to get this working but should do what you want.

3) Accept the page reload - accept this is the trade-off when using Web Forms and leave as is.

4) Move to something like MVC which does not have the Postback model.

Sounds like you probably need to do some reading into Web Forms and look at the Pros and Cons and make an informed decision as at the moment you are trying to fight the framework rather than work with it.